# Migrate Application.Settings from Local to Roaming

Tags: c#, .net

My application has so far stored settings in %APPDATA%/Local - all this is handled by the default Application.Settings.

We're trying to upgrade this to store in %APPDATA%/Roaming, to support a virtualisation setup. The settings save fine, but saved preferences from previous versions are lost.

We previously upgraded between versions using `Settings.Default.Upgrade()`, however, this doesn't seem to map between Local and Roaming settings. Is there another API solution, or would we need to manually map between the two versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually map this.

I believe the best approach should be create a Settings-like file into Roaming (you may or not utilize XML format) and manually store/read its contents.

Even if you locate it at ROAMING but try to utilize it in the My.Settings context, the Settings will be created at the default location.